# Why does this appear in the VSCode terminal? How do I make it not take so long to run the code?

Tags: java, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am programming in Java in Vscode. The situation is that the code takes a considerable time to execute, when I would think it should be almost instantaneous. I get the message: "Loading personal and system profiles took Xms". I don't know what it means and I don't know if it is related to the fact that the terminal took time to execute the code.

Do you know why this happens and how to fix it? It would be like speeding up Vscode's terminal response time or something. Thank you!

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dayyP.png)
I have updated Powershell but there was no change in Vscode